# Issue when trying to assign value to an input tag based on ID

Tags: jquery

I am struggling to find out what's wrong here. I use Jquery in order to create a div element, which includes several children elements.
This div is created on a button click and has an ID taken by a variable:

```
        operator_list = 'something';
        single_value_input = 'something_else';
        input = attribute_list + operator_list + single_value_input;
        input_id = attribute_list;

        // create input text area with id of the single value
        $("#added_rules").append( '<div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-btn" id="erase_query"><a href="#"  class="btn btn-primary btn-mg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" title="Help" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></a></div><input type="text" class="form-control" id="' + input_id + '" placeholder="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" readonly></br></div>');
```

Then I try to place some values inside the input tag by using jquery:

```
$("#" + input_id).val(input);
```

And it doesn't work. Nothing happens and I get no errors in the Developers Tool.
The assigned ID of the input tag is generated based on the user's input and is in the form of: 'NAME_1>24' Perhaps the issue is related with escaped characters..

When I try to assign to the input_id a string instead of assigning to it a variable then it works. But this is not what I want.

Comment: i hope you have a `var input_id` somewhere in your code

Comment: I do declare input_id on top of the question. You say that I should declare it as: var input_id? That would make it a global variable. Why would I want this?

Comment: @dkar madalin should have tagged his comment as *offtopic* (or 'unrelated') as it's not event remotely relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because your "ID" contains CSS selectors that `$("#"+selector)` is picking up.

```
$("#" + input_id).val(input);
```

becomes

```
$("#NAME_1>24").val(input);
```

which says find all "24" elements that are child items of #NAME_1 - which obvious makes no sense.

Easiest option is to not include css selectors in your IDs.

If this is not possible, you can use attribute match, eg:

```
$("['id=" + input_id + "']").val(input);
```

but this won't be very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate the value directly in the append

```
$("#added_rules").append( '<div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-btn" id="erase_query"><a href="#"  class="btn btn-primary btn-mg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" title="Help" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></a></div><input type="text" class="form-control" id="' + input_id + '" placeholder="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" readonly value="'.value.'"></br></div>');
```

Comment: Didn't think of that. I tried it like this and it works but I wonder if its a good practice to set the ID of an element with characters like: <>= etc.

Comment: @dkar why not use a class?

Comment: these seems more like a xy problem